# Vimeo js API load video

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm loading inside a player with options a new vimeo id.
The video is loaded and playable inside player but the options (portrait, title, ..) are not used.

here's the code used to create the player (on ready)

```
var iframe = $('#vimeoContainer');
var options = {
    id : 191611447,
    portrait: 0,
    title : 0,
    byline: 0,
};

var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe, options);
```

and here's the code to load a video insite this player

```
  player.loadVideo(sl).then(function(id) {
// the video successfully loaded
}).catch(function(error) {
switch (error.name) {
    case 'TypeError':
        // the id was not a number
        break;

    case 'PasswordError':
        // the video is password-protected and the viewer needs to enter the
        // password first
        break;

    case 'PrivacyError':
        // the video is password-protected or private
        break;

    default:
        // some other error occurred
        break;
}
});
```

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: You set title and byline to 0 (false), so title and byline are not shown, you get what you ask form. To fix this just do not set the options (delete it) or set it to 1. More Info: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed

Answer (score 0):

You set title and byline to 0 (false), so title and byline are not shown, you get what you ask for. To fix this just do not set the options (delete it) or set it to 1/true.

```
var options = {
    id : 191611447,
    portrait: 0,
    title : true, // its the default anyway
    byline: true, // its the default anyway
};
```

or:

```
var options = {
    id : 191611447,
    portrait: 0,
};
```

More Info: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed